# Microsoft Graph: OData $select query parameter doesn't select

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

[The MS Graph 'Get a user' documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get) says:

> If you need a different property set, you can use the OData $select
>   query parameter

but it appears not to work, either in my code or in the Graph Explorer. In both, the query
 `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=displayName` returns the
**full set** of user properties:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(surname)/$entity",
    "displayName": "<my name>",
    "surname": "<my surname>",
    "givenName": "<my given name>",
    "id": "<my <my ID>>",
    "userPrincipalName": "<my email>",
    "businessPhones": [<my phones>],
    "jobTitle": <my job title>,
    "mail": null,
    "mobilePhone": null,
    "officeLocation": null,
    "preferredLanguage": null
}
```

How can I get my desired subset of user properties (e.g. just the displayName)?

[EDITED]

In response to Lee_MSFT's Graph Explorer screenshot below, here's what I get from the exact same query:
[image]

... so why the difference? What's going off-beam with my query?

Comment: This is the Graph Explorer request ID:
`request-id: b3a3fc10-63d4-448f-9177-d24ba50dbdfe`

Comment: ... and the request ID from my own JS request via Ajax:

`request-id: 1c56cc3a-51d9-405e-9eb3-409d06e060d6`

Comment: Do you see the same output when you the sample query which being authenticated? Means - open `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#` in incognito window and run the query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/?$select=displayName`.

Comment: Well now, this is interesting: if I open Graph Explorer in an incognito window and run the same query via the sample account, I do just get the displayName: 
`{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName)/$entity",
    "displayName": "Megan Bowen"
}` - and then, if I log into my own MS account and run the exact same query, I get the full set of properties!! So what conclusion can we draw from that?

Comment: Can this issue due to Multi tenant configuration? May be try with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/<<Your Tenant>>/me?$select=displayName`?

Comment: Thanks for your very plausible suggestion, user1672994. However, we're not using a multi tenant configuration, so there's no question of configuring the query to my individual tenant. But it would seem to be some property of my account. I've tried modifying my permissions, to no effect. Any further suggestions will be greatly welcomed!!

Comment: I would suggest to raise a issue at https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=request

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your helpful interest,  user1672994.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you're using a personal Microsoft Account (sometimes referred to as an MSA or an Outlook.com account), where as Lee is using an Office 365 account. I reproduce your behavior when I use an MSA, but do not in Office 365. MSA accounts behave a little differently in Graph. I'll report this to the Graph folks.

In the meantime, is there something that's breaking for you? I know you're getting more properties than you want, but at least nothing is missing :).

Comment: Thanks very much, Jason. This will be the explanation. Nothing is breaking for me. `$select=displayName` gives me more properties than I need, but as you say, nothing is missing and I can easily do my own selection from there. Thanks very much for your offer to report this (undocumented!) behaviour to the Graph folks.

Comment: Yep! As it turns out this is a known limitation, and we'll update the docs to call it out.

Comment: @JasonJohnston Were the docs ever updated on this?  Is there a link?  I'm having same issue 3 years later.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test result which works fine.
[image]

Comment: @mx0 Tim Windsor Brown

Point taken. I needed to post an image to show the difference between Lee_MSFT's Graph Explorer outcome and mine. I couldn't see a way of doing this in a comment. However, I've now edited my question to include my image, though it makes the sequencing of responses a bit odd.
Still hoping for a fuller answer to my question ;)

Comment: Thanks for your useful feedback, Lee_MSFT. What's your answer to the question as to why I get such a different response to the exact same query?

Comment: How about a different user (users/userid?$select=displayName) or a different server?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried two other users - same result. I'm not sure how Graph Explorer could be accessed on a different server?

Comment: Just try to access graph-explorer on a different server and login with your Microsoft account(or other type of account).

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question: How exactly could I access Graph Explorer on a different server? What URL could I use?